# Link not visible while extracting from a python script in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have a made a python script which scrapes out a **particular** link from a list of links, the problem is, whenever i try to load the link via the script, that **particular** link is not visible, but if i try to open the link(which has the sublink) via browser, the sublink open up.

For ex:-

```
<a href="http://daclips.in/qx9ecuy1geum" class="push_button blue" style="width:290px; height:70px; font-weight:normal; font-size:22px; line-height:65px; margin:0px auto 20px auto;">Click Here to Play</a>
```

I am trying to extract the link from a href via (`http://onwatchseries.to/cale.html?r=aHR0cDovL2RhY2xpcHMuaW4vNzhzNmE4M3Zra2Y2`), & the link loads up in the browser, but.. if I try to open the same link via script, I get.

```
document.write('<a href="' + decoded + '" class="push_button blue" style="width:290px; height:70px; font-weight:normal; font-size:22px; line-height:65px; margin:0px auto 20px auto;">Click Here to Play</a>');
```

How to solve this ?

Below is my script.

```
for i in range(1, 25):
    dicts.setdefault(str(i), [])
    url = "http://onwatchseries.to/episode/seinfeld_s4_e"+str(i)+".html"
    content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a',{'title':'daclips.in'}):
        list.append(link.get('href'))
        dicts[str(i)].append(link.get('href'))


for k in list:
    c = urllib2.urlopen(k).read()
    s = BeautifulSoup(c,"lxml")
    for m in s.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://daclips.in/")}):
        print m.get('href')
```

In this script, there is just no output, I tried sleep for 10 seconds, that still does not help.

Comment: As usual with questions about BS and something not appearing: the tag is loaded dynamically with javascript, so urllib/requests cannot include it. You can try to use for example Selenium instead.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments pointed out, you will probably need to use selenium to scrape the page you are looking at in your browser.
Selenium + a webdriver (PhantomJS, Chromedriver, Firefox) will allow the page to be accessed as though you were using your browser. If you don't wish a browser window to open then your best bet would be PhantomJS.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import Webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'your URL'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('path to webdriver')
browser.get(url)
sleep(5)
***your find_element code***
```

Also, you will need to sleep to let the page load (or use WebDriverWait())